# Updating a table in MySQL causes an error when using Entry from TKinter when the value is the form XX_YY_ZZ but works without the underline

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, tkinter

UPDATE: I thought it might be better to mention in the code that the list is generated from tk.Entry.

Updating a column in MySQL doesn't work when the value has underlines in it.

The column is in the string format, and the value to be updated is taken from a list.

The Error: Unknown column '2020_05_01' in 'field list'

If list_tu = [2020_05_01, 2020_05_02] # ===> DOESN'T WORK

If list_tu = [2, 3] # ===> WORKS

P.S. if I change the column format to DATE, then I get the following error when I enter this value 2020-05-01 into the tkinter Entry field:

Incorrect date value: '2014' for column 'Expiration_date' at row 1

```
        entries = [Entry(self.edit_wind, font =('Calibri', 7 )) for _ in range(2)]
        for entry in entries:
            entry.pack()            
        list_tu = list()
        def get_entry():
            for entry in entries:
                data_1 = entry.get()
                list_tu.append(data_1)
            return list_tu

        ids_list = [8, 9]
        def insert_tu():
            conn = connection_forward_db
            cursor = conn.cursor()        
            for tu, ids in zip(list_tu, ids_list):
                cursor.execute('UPDATE tableA SET Expiration_date = '+tu+' WHERE DB_id = '+str(ids)+'')
                conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: The reason for the specific error message here is that the MySQL query requires quotes to be put around string values. To demonstrate, with your current code the query generated will be this, even if you specify your underlined dates as strings in the original list:

```
UPDATE tableA SET Expiration_date = 2020_05_01 WHERE DB_id = 8
```

What you want it to look like is this:

```
UPDATE tableA SET Expiration_date = '2020_05_01' WHERE DB_id = 8
```

So you need to add some quotes to your original execute line as follows:

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE tableA SET Expiration_date = \''+tu+'\' WHERE DB_id = '+str(ids)+'')
```

These have to be escaped with `\` to prevent python interpreting them as delimiters for your string. You could also use double quotes as your delimiters to avoid having to escape them:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE tableA SET Expiration_date = '"+tu+"' WHERE DB_id = "+str(ids)+"")
```

Another suggestion I would have is to use [parameterised queries](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/a-guide-to-mysql-prepared-statements-and-parameterized-queries.html), rather than splicing variable values directly into your query string. If those values are coming from user input (or have any chance of doing so in the future), the query could be prone to a [SQL injection attack](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). It's not clear what connection library you are using to connect to MySQL here, but all the good ones should provide some way to use parameterised queries. Using parameterised queries also means you don't have to worry about things like making sure quotes are added in your query string.

As an additional piece of advice, there is a `date` type in MySQL that may be better suited to your needs for storing the `Expiration_date` field. Using that type will allow you to compare other dates against it and other useful functionality (like getting the day of the week from the date for example). In that case, the dates would need to be provided as follows:

```
list_tu = ["2020-05-01", "2020-05-02"]
```

(Other formats will be accepted, but not underlines as far as I know.)

Comment: Dear Rob, thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I have tried both ways, with quotes and  \ , but then I get the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '2020_05_05' WHERE DB_id = 9' at line 1

Comment: And when I use DATE format, I get this error: Incorrect date value: '2014' for column 'Expiration_date' at row 1. (eventhough I have entered 2020-05-01 into the Entry field)

Comment: Also, I use TKinter Entry widget to generate the list with strings. I have added the function to the code.

Comment: Ok, since it seems like there's a syntax error now that looks like progress. Can you try printing the query out before it's passed to cursor.execute() and pasting it here? I can't see a syntax error with the specific snippet in that error message.

Comment: hmm. I added print('UPDATE '+table_name+' Expiration_date = \''+tu+'\' WHERE DB_id = '+str(ids)+'')  in the for loop before the cursor.execute(), and this is what got printed: UPDATE forwarderAAAA Expiration_date = '20' WHERE DB_id = 9

Comment: Ok, your issue there seems to be that you are missing the `SET` keyword after `forwarderAAAA`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have underlines in a list with integers. You cannot have underlines in an integer. If you need the underline then put quotes around it to make it a string. For example:

```
    list_tu = ["2020_05_01", "2020_05_02"]
```

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, the values are in string originally, as the list is generated from tk.Entry which gives strings

Comment: I have tried to use the date format, but then, after entering 2020-05-01 into the Entry, I get error: Incorrect date value: '2014' for column 'Expiration_date' at row 1